# LabVIEW - Specify network card from multiple

Tags: networking, labview

Short story:
Is it possible to specify the network card I want the LabView application to connect to the server?

Long story:
I have a LabVIEW application running on customer test machine in a remote location. The application is responsible for two things: 1) test component, 2) connect with customer server to provide some information about the sample (i.e.: status of the sample after test). Testing of the component works without issue, the problem is customer network. Apparently, there is no possibility for remote connection from customer site using customer network. During the delivery we found a workaround by plugging a USB WiFi card and connecting with it to a hotspot from smartphone. Such solution however has a problem, the application tries to connect to the customer server through the USB WiFi card, not the customer network. Is it possible to solve this issue somehow? Is it possible to choose by which network card, the application has to connect to the server?

I tried to use the VISA write/read vi's, but without any luck.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with the Windows routing table. From the error description it sounds like the customer server is not on the local net but behind a router on the customer net. Correct? In that case you need to [add a second route](https://serverfault.com/questions/570439/setting-a-static-route-for-a-specific-network-adapter-with-two-network-adapters) that goes through that gateway when accessing an IP in the customer's IP address range

Comment: I vote to close this. Network configuration is outside the scope of SO. Serverfault is a better community for this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally turned out to be network configuration issue, as Homer512 suggested.